# Unable to run Talend Open Studio for Data Integration 8.0.1 due to older JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, environment-variables, talend

I wanted to run "Talend Open Studio for Data Integration 8.0.1" which giving following error.
[image]

I have configured JDK 8 in JAVA_HOME with is my windows level variable.
**I wanted to configure talend to run on latest JDK 18 from local path and not from JAVA_HOME.**

Is there any way to run talend with other than JAVA_HOME environment variable reference?

Tried with -vm parameter similar to Eclipse IDE we run with specified Java Path.

Comment: SUGGESTION: Create a .bat file for running Talend.  It will set the correct Windows environment variables (including both %JAVA_HOME% and %PATH%) that point your Java 18 JRE. NOTE: It's the *JRE* that matters; not the JDK.

Answer (score 4):

Edit the .ini file in talend installation directory and change first line from -vm to -vmargs
C:/path/to/java/bin
Replace above path to latest version